# Installing applications temporarily

Tags: software-recommendation

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. To post some answers I may need to install some applications which I won't use much. So I would love to install those apps in way that they are gone after a restart.

How can I do this?

Comment: A virtual machine with a snapshot after fresh installation, which you revert to after each experiment. If you want a non-VM solution, look at `UnionFS` but things will probably get messy.

Comment: I am sorry I can't go for that because I have only 2 GB of RAM and I can't run VM all the time

Comment: 2 GB is plenty. You should be able to run Ubuntu in a VM without an issue. Did you try?

Comment: Well now a days the Ubuntu Recommended RAM size is 1GB and I will run some other applications like players,browsers parallel to VM and my PC cant hold that for long time.

Comment: **1** Why do you specify 13.10? If you wish to "post some answers", wouldn't the questions relate to non-alpha and non-beta versions of Ubuntu? **2** why can't you just purge the unwanted applications when you're done with them?

Comment: @vasa1 yes everytime you want me to do that ? I dont like to do.I want something I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

Try overlayfs. I've used it lots of places. Here are the steps to set it up (it's really easy)

Note: this will sandbox your whole system until you either remove the mount or restart. The way I describe it, it's an all-or-nothing situation. Either you're sandboxing everything (browser history, changed settings, etc.) or nothing at all. If you do some research you might be able to tweak it more to your needs, but give it a try!

First, make the directory to host your sandbox:

```
mkdir /tmp/sandbox
```

Now, mount that bad boy

```
sudo mount -t overlayfs -o upperdir=/tmp/sandbox,lowerdir=/ overlayfs /
```

That's it! You should now be running a sandboxed machine! When you reboot /tmp/sandbox should be gone.

Comment: Thinking about it a little harder, I may have to retract my answer. If the sandbox exists in /tmp and it's caching /, then it may create an infinite circular logic: write new data to /tmp/sandbox, something in /tmp/sandbox changed, write changes to /tmp/sandbox. One way around this problem may be to set up a ramdrive or tempfs mount on either /tmp or some other arbitrary location.

Comment: Either actually not exactly I want but nearer some what thank you. +1 . Did I mention a complex task.

Comment: It's exactly what you asked for. How can I tailor it more to your needs?

Comment: i don't like to turn my whole system into a sandbox.

Comment: @rajagenupula Then turn only those directories that the apps are installed to into a sandbox ( if you make an overlay for /usr /lib* /bin /sbin /etc /var /opt ... don't know exactly what filesystem structure ubuntu is using, but about everything except for home)

Comment: The thing is, you can't choose where to install .deb packages. They're going to go into the system directories. So, you could sandbox the entire system or you could sandbox every single individual directory that might host files from the application: /usr (/usr/lib /usr/share), /var, /etc, /home, /tmp and probably more. It's easier to sandbox the whole thing and just restart or drop the sandbox when you're done.